# Best way in objective-c to turn XML like structure to dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing

I have a query output which looks like this:

```
<ticker-entry gamecode=\"2015050110\" gametype=\"Playoffs\"><visiting-team display_name=\"Tampa Bay\" alias=\"TB\" nickname=\"Lightning\" id=\"20\" division=\"ECA\" conference=\"EC\" score=\"2\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"0\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"0\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"1\"></score><score heading=\"OT\" value=\"0\"></score><score heading=\"OT2\" value=\"1\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"2\"></score></visiting-team><home-team display_name=\"Montreal\" alias=\"Mon\" nickname=\"Canadiens\" id=\"10\" division=\"ECA\" conference=\"EC\" score=\"1\"><score heading=\"1\" value=\"0\"></score><score heading=\"2\" value=\"0\"></score><score heading=\"3\" value=\"1\"></score><score heading=\"OT\" value=\"0\"></score><score heading=\"OT2\" value=\"0\"></score><score heading=\"T\" value=\"1\"></score></home-team><gamestate status=\"Final\" display_status1=\"Final\" display_status2=\"2OT\" href=\"http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/nhl/recap.asp?g=2015050110\" tv=\"NBCS/CBC\" gametime=\"7:00 PM\" gamedate=\"5/1\" is-dst=\"1\" is-world-dst=\"1\"></gamestate></ticker-entry>
```

It looks like XML but the XML parser I wrote can't do anything with this since the brackets have attributs not only a single word like in normale xml

```
<foo>
  <bar>Value</bar>
</foo>
```

So what would be a good way in objective-c to split this string into a logic structure?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `\"` marks with `"`, it parses as fully valid XML. I think that's your only problem.